# How can I exclude dependencies brought in from other sub-projects?

Tags: gradle, dependencies

This is not a duplicate since those other solutions did not work.

I have a sub-project:

:commons:widget

gradle.build (sub-project) resembles this:

```
configurations {providedCompile}

dependencies {
  compile project(":commons:other-widget")
...other dependencies...
}
```

If you display the dependencies:

```
+--- project :commons:some-other-project
    +--- project :commons:exclude-me-project (*)
    \--- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs: -> 3.0.3 (*)
```

What doesn't work:

Any of the usual syntax. I've tried every variation I can think of. Even went looking for the API but was unable to find what I need there.

In this project's dependencies section:
...

```
compile project(":commons:some-other-project") {
 exclude (":commons:exclude-me-project")
}
```

Result:

```
Could not find method exclude() for arguments [:commons:some-other-project] on project
```

I've also tried:

```
compile ( project (':commons:some-other-project') ) {
  transitive = false
}
```

Result: Instead of removing dependencies of ":commons:some-other-project", it removes ":commons:some-other-project".

I have a large and complicated project to convert. I've a lot of this sort of work ahead of me. Given a project as a dependency, how do I exclude things from it?

Comment: Have you tried `exclude("groupID:ModuleID")` ?

Comment: or `transitive=false`

Comment: Re: transitive=false  There's little point in having subprojects and trying to re-use stuff if your going to exclude everything willy nilly.  I need something specific.

Comment: @RaGe What I've noticed is that Maven does things like groupId:projectId but if your subcomponent is :something:somethingelse:yetevensomethingelse, what is your groupId:projectId?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

`exclude` for dependencies has a little bit another syntax, so try to do it providing the module name, which is equals to the `exclude-me-project` name, like:

```
compile(project(":commons:some-other-project")) {
    exclude module: "exclude-me-project"
}
```

Alternatively, you may exclude all the transitive dependencies for `commons` project, but it will remove all the deps of the `some-other-project` project, including the `exclude-me-project`:

```
compile(project(":commons:some-other-project")) {
    transitive = false
}
```

Comment: Already tried exclude module but will double-check to be certain. It may not have been under the right circumstances. transitive=false is not very specific. It's like using a nuclear weapon to swat a mosquito.

Comment: @user447607 just don't forget to place a `project` into `(` and `)` as it's done in the answer. Not `compile project(":commons:some-other-project")`, but `compile(project(":commons:some-other-project"))`. I've tested it yet, but with a little bit another project structure

Answer (score 6):

for new gradle syntax you can do something like:

```
implementation (project(path: ':my_library_v1.0.0')) {
    exclude (group: 'com.google.code.gson', module: 'gson')
}
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Kotlin DSL answer

This will exclude a subproject from another subproject:

```
implementation(project(":nice-subproject")) {
    exclude(module = "annoying-transitive-subproject")
}
```

Also note that using `exclude` on a test fixture dependency requires a cast

```
implementation(testFixtures(project(":nice-subproject")) as ModuleDependency) {
    exclude(module = "annoying-transitive-subproject")
}
```